# The best way to get BlackBerry 10 logs?

Tags: blackberry-10, blackberry-ndk

BlackBerry 10 has quite sophisticated logs system compared to iOS and Android.
The only solution i found is using `javaloader` tool like this:

```
javaloader.exe -u eventlog > eventlog.txt
```

But it seems to work only with pre-10 versions of BlackBerry OS. I cannot find this tool in BlackBerry 10 NDK.

What is the simplest method to get the logs using the command line?

Comment: Are you tried [this](http://btsc.webapps.blackberry.com/btsc/viewdocument.do;jsessionid=8B65359757AC2078B347497A3AAFF444?externalId=KB34114&sliceId=2&cmd=displayKC&docType=kc&noCount=true&ViewedDocsListHelper=com.kanisa.apps.common.BaseViewedDocsListHelperImpl) solution?

Comment: @CAMOBAP: yes, but ``-getFile`` works faster for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two ways, both documented in the [release notes](https://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/download/releasenotes/).

If you can copy the logger stream (for an application) to the console by defining a function like:

```
void myMessageOutput(QtMsgType type, const char* msg) {
    fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", msg);
    fflush(stdout);
}
```

Then installing it as a message handler:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    Application app(argc, argv);
    qInstallMsgHandler(myMessageOutput);
    ...
}
```

You can connect to the simulator or device with an ssh system and use the slog2info command.

Comment: Debug versions built by Momentics will produce a core file. QNX developer support people at BlackBerry events consistently recommend analyzing the core dump in Momentics.

Comment: It's the new topic of blackberry devblog: http://devblog.blackberry.com/2012/10/blackberry-10-sdk-console-logging

Comment: @Hithredin: any chance to do it without Qt?

Comment: I do not know. With native I used Gameplay and their log system, but I haven't see a way to get crash log, etc...

Answer (score 9):

You can also SSH onto the device (ssh devuser@169.254.0.1) and run:

```
slog2info -w
```

Which will display the slogger2 logs.

Comment: What needs to be done before you can log in using SSH? I had to add my public RSA key to the authorized_keys2 file using the target file system explorer in Momentics before I could log in. I don't think they meant it to be that complex, so maybe I missed something :)

Comment: telnet seems to work as well and does not need a key but I did not find the logs useful in my case

Answer (score 6):

Here is what i have found moving away from Momentics IDE to command line.

When application does `printf()` the output goes into the file

```
/accounts/1000/appdata/[your application folder name]/logs/log
```

You can use this command

```
blackberry-deploy -getFile [path-to-log]
```

to bring that file to your PC. Also, you can use target filesystem navigator from the IDE to inspect this (or any other) file.

Answer (score 4):

This is similar to another answer but with additional details that will be useful for momentics users (BlackBerry 10 IDE)

**1. Enable the terminal view in the momentics IDE**

Window --> Show view --> Other --> Terminal

Select the terminal and press OK

**2. Connect to the terminal**

Select the Terminal tab (possibly called 'Terminal 1') in your views window.
Select the connect button, it's a green N shaped button on the top right of the top right of the views window.

**3. Run the log viewer command**

```
$ slog2info -w
```

To read more info about this command:

```
$ slog2info --help
```

*Note that there shouldn't be any need to provide an ssh user or keys, that is taken care of by the IDE when you use this procedure.

**Log statements**

You can add logging to your app with the following commands

```
qDebug() << "This is debug";
qWarning() << "This is a warning";
qCritical() << "This is critical " << somevariable << ", some additional text";
qFatal() << "This is fatal" << somevariable;
```

Comment: Dont u get the same on the console on a debug run??? My app works in debug mode but it crashes in release ....In a release mode I get nothing using the slog2info

Comment: The IDE may have gone through changes since last year. Release is another ball game, I'll update my answer to cover that at the weekend.

Answer (score -1):

You can view all the logs from the following path

```
/accounts/1000/appdata/[Application Name]/logs/log
```