# Android-app on Blackberry 10 does not start - how to debug?

Tags: android, blackberry-10, blackberry-android

I got an Android apk app here that is supposed to run on Blackberry. I converted it with apk2bar, signed it with my debug token. The device also has the debug token installed and developer mode enabled. Installing the app with blackberry-deploy went fine and the app appears on the home screen. When started, the app asks for permissions (GPS etc), after confirming it says "Initializing", then the app just disappears without any errors.

How can I find out what's going wrong?

Comment: are sure that you don't have any restricted api code such as google map, native code... ?

Comment: Yeah, I had some references to Google maps in it.

Comment: comment out all restricted api codes and try it again. probably it will work.

Comment: Already did, thanks! 
I wish I could just close this question now.

Answer (score 0):

To develop and debug android application in blackberry 10 OS device / emulator, you will need to install [Blackberry Android Tools](http://developer.blackberry.com/android/tools/). You will still need the usual [Android Development Tools](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html), because that's where you get LogCat window.

Answer (score 0):

Check for Google API like Google Maps or Play related calls. If you remove all that check if it works.

About viewing logs on BlackBerry 10 you can check this: 
[The best way to get BlackBerry 10 logs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13112383/the-best-way-to-get-blackberry-10-logs)