# How to extract event log from blackberry 10 device?

Tags: android, blackberry-10, blackberry-android

I have a blackberry 10 device with an android app sideloaded onto it. 
I need to get an event log/logcat/log file (not sure what its called) while the issue in the application is occurring (so via command prompt) How do I do that?

What commands, paths do I follow? I have all the JDE, JDK, APK, JavaLoader, Eclipse, etc downloaded but I don't know what to use, which path to take.

Comment: Possible duplicate. Check this question out:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13112383/the-best-way-to-get-blackberry-10-logs

Comment: Do you want to see the logcat while device is connected to your PC and IDE is running? Or do you need it offline?

Comment: I'm so new to this that I don't even know what IDE is. All i know is that it's downloaded onto my PC. Here's what I need: My blackberry is connected to my PC and I need to reproduce my defect that I found on an android application which was sideloaded onto my blackberry. And get a log while my bug is being reproduced. :D @Schlangi

Comment: OK, fine. IDE stands for Integrated Development Environment (or something similar, don't blame me...) - in your case, it is Eclipse.

Comment: Sorry for "double commenting"... But you sideloaded it using Eclipse? Or other way? Do you have the sources, or just apk?

Comment: I dragged my .bar file into playbook > PB Installer. if you need any more info let me know, i'll try to provide it. If you could help me that would be amazing!

Answer (score 0):

Download de Command Line tools and use:

```
blackberry-deploy -getFile [path-to-log]
```

Check this for more info: [The best way to get BlackBerry 10 logs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13112383/the-best-way-to-get-blackberry-10-logs)